Turing machine that makes exactly $2^{|x|}$ steps on any input $x$
I have the following problem:
Construct a Turing-machine that makes exactly $2^{|x|}$ steps on any input $x$. The machine can have $k$ tapes but only a fixed number of states (thus, the number of states cannot depend on $x$).
Here, a step constitutes reading the current symbol, writing a symbol to the current cell and moving the head left/right by one cell.
I thought about creating a binary counter that counts from $0$ to $2^n - 1$, however, one incrementation would involve several steps. I assume that the machine should keep track of the number steps it has made but checking whether it should halt and incrementing the counter should also be made in one step.

How many steps (exactly) takes a binary counter from $0$ to $2^n-1$?

The problem is that when I increase a number like 111 the head is currently at least significant digit (since I incremented 110 before) and I need to move the head 3 to the left (while also swapping every 1 to a 0) and write a 1 in the next empty cell, resulting in 1000. So one incrementation takes several steps and will exceed 2^n.
